# Mask R-CNN, Multi-Class

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am following the classic balloon example of Mask R-CNN. I trained the model with 2 classes, vehicle and bottle. Now the model perfectly detects both of the objects but It says vehicle (class_id=1) to all of them, where it would say all bottles are vehicle. I probably made some mistakes while configuring the code. Does anybody have an idea about this issue?

Changed the number of classes in the config.py (1 + nb classes)
Added these classes in load_ in the custom dataset class

But I think I need to do one more thing and It is about here:

```
 for a in annotations:
        # print(a)
        # Get the x, y coordinates of points of the polygons that make up
        # the outline of each object instance. There are stores in the
        # shape_attributes (see json format above)
        polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions'].values()]

        # load_mask() needs the image size to convert polygons to masks.
        # Unfortunately, VIA doesn't include it in JSON, so we must read
        # the image. This is only managable since the dataset is tiny.
        image_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, a['filename'])
        image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
        height, width = image.shape[:2]

        self.add_image(
            "vehicle",  ## for a single class just add the name here
            image_id=a['filename'],  # use file name as a unique image id
            path=image_path,
            width=width, height=height,
            polygons=polygons)
```

I couldn't figure out what to change in here. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call the function `self.add_image(....)` in your `for loop`, you should check which class your image belongs to. If it belongs to `vehicle`, you call:

```
self.add_image("vehicle", ...)
```

If it belongs to `bottle`, you should call:

```
self.add_image("bottle", ...)
```

Additionally, in your `config` file, in addition to setting `NUM_CLASSES` to `1+nb_classes`, you must have given your configuration a name, e.g., "`vehicle_and_bottle`". Then, in your `load` function, you should add these:

```
self.add_class("vehicle_and_bottle", 1, "bottle") # first class
self.add_class("vehicle_and_bottle", 2, "vehicle") # second class
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/s0piy7 , http://prntscr.com/s0pksh, do you mean like that?

Comment: yes, if names refers to either bottle or vehicle, this should work

Comment: self.add_images("vehicle_and_bottle) is required. I need to type the name of the config to that string